# Excel VBA Match Split Search String

Tags: excel, vba, search, match

Is there a way to split a search by each word and compare partial matches in Excel?

For example,
If my table contains:

```
example test phrase | result1
phrase test two     | result2
excluded phrase     | result3
```

If I search with: (Using A1 as the search field)

```
searchString = "*test phrase*"
searchItem = Application.Match(searchString, Worksheets("Table").Range("A2:A100"), 0)
```

This returns only result 1, but not result 2 as it is looking for the entire phrase, only in the order it was typed.

With the search string "test phrase" entered, I need result1 AND result2 to return, without including result3. (In this example)

Does Excel/VBA have any built in way to do this?

Comment: Use split and iterate the table then iterate the words and use instr to see if they exist.  Making sure all words exist in the phrase.

Comment: Could the search phrase have more than two words? And do the words have to be next to each other (e.g. 'phrase test two' *is* a match but 'phrase two test' *is not* a match)?

Comment: Hi Alex sorry for not including that. Yes, the search could be longer, but should never include words not found in the result.

Comment: I don't think there is an integrated way to do this.
What you can do is iterate the cells of the range and use the Instr function or the Like operator as you like and add the results to an array or collection of your choice.

Comment: What do you want to do when a match is found? Do you want to write it somewhere, copy the whole row or...?

Comment: Hi VBasic2008, we just need this to select a row from the table that best matches and return the row number, so that we can then get the cell that was found. So just needing the row number.

Answer (score 0):

If you have windows Excel O365, you can do this with a formula:

```
D6: =FILTER($B$2:$B$100,IFERROR(SEARCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),$A$2:$A$100),FALSE))
```

***Note:** If you want to return the contents of the matching cell, rather than what wrote in your question, merely change `B2:B100 --> A2:A100`*

[image]

Answer (score -1):

### Sub Strings of a String in Another String

**Upside Down**

- For the task you mentioned in the comments, you will probably only need the last, the 3rd procedure, the function.
- The 2nd procedure is a practical example of how to use the function.
- The 1st procedure is a practical example of how to use the 2nd procedure.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

' How to use 'getMatchingValues'.
Sub testGetMatchingValues()
    
    ' Initialize error handling.
    Const ProcName As String = "testGetMatchingValues"
    On Error GoTo clearError ' Turn on error trapping.
    
    ' Source
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const rngAddress As String = "A2:A100"
    ' Target
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const tgtFirstCell As String = "A2"
    ' Other
    Const SearchString = "test phrase"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook with this code.
    
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(rngAddress)
    
    ' Write values that contain all sub strings of Search String to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    getMatchingValues Data, rng, SearchString
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to Target Range.
    Set rng = wb.Worksheets(tgtName).Range(tgtFirstCell)
                                    .Resize (UBound(Data) - LBound(Data) + 1)
    rng.Value = Application.Transpose(Data)
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Done.", vbInformation, "Success"

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
    GoTo ProcExit

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' In each cell of a column range ('ColumnRange'), searches for each sub string
' of a specified string ('SearchString').
' If all sub strings are found, writes the value of the cell
' to a 1D array ('Result1D').
' The search is by default case-sensitive i.e. 'A<>a' (ignoreCase = False).
' It uses the 'foundAllStrings' function.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub getMatchingValues(ByRef Result1D As Variant, _
                      ColumnRange As Range, _
                      ByVal SearchString As String, _
                      Optional ByVal ignoreCase = False)
    
    ' Initialize error handling.
    Const ProcName As String = "getMatchingValues"
    On Error GoTo clearError ' Turn on error trapping.
    
    ' Reset Result Array.
    Result1D = Empty
    
    ' Validate Column Range.
    If ColumnRange Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    ' Write values from first column of Column Range to Source Array.
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ColumnRange.Columns(1)
    Dim Source As Variant
    If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        Source = rng.Value
    Else
        ReDim Source(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        Source(1, 1) = rng.Value
    End If
    
    ' Write values from Source Array to Result Array.
    ReDim Result1D(0 To UBound(Source) - 1)
    Dim k As Long: k = LBound(Result1D) - 1
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Source)
        If foundAllStrings(SearchString, Source(i, 1), ignoreCase) Then
            k = k + 1
            Result1D(k) = Source(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Resize Result Array.
    If k >= LBound(Result1D) Then
        ReDim Preserve Result1D(LBound(Result1D) To k)
    Else
        Result1D = Empty
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
    GoTo ProcExit

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' In a specified string ('SuperString'), searches for each sub string
' of another specified string ('SearchString').
' If all sub strings are found, it returns 'True', otherwise 'False'.
' The search is by default case-sensitive i.e. 'A<>a' (ignoreCase = False).
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function foundAllStrings(SearchString As String, _
                         ByVal SuperString As String, _
                         Optional ByVal ignoreCase = False) As Boolean
    
    ' Initialize error handling.
    Const ProcName As String = "foundAllStrings"
    On Error GoTo clearError ' Turn on error trapping.
    
    ' Determine case sensitivity.
    Dim iCase As Long
    If ignoreCase Then
        iCase = 1 ' vbTextCompare
    End If
    
    ' Write sub strings of Search String to Sub Strings Array.
    Dim SubStrings As Variant
    SubStrings = Split(SearchString) ' " " by default
    
    ' Check each sub string if it is contained in Super String.
    Dim j As Long
    For j = LBound(SubStrings) To UBound(SubStrings)
        If InStr(1, SuperString, SubStrings(j), iCase) = 0 Then
            GoTo ProcExit
        End If
    Next j
    
    ' All sub strings were found in Super String.
    foundAllStrings = True
  
ProcExit:
    Exit Function

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
    GoTo ProcExit

End Function
```